# How does the Spanish legal system determine cases of vicarious abuse?

Tags: child-abuse, spain, abuse

According to [this article](https://www.niusdiario.es/sociedad/sucesos/violencia-vicaria-breton-parricida-morana-hijos-asesinados_18_3152372218.html) in Spanish, the Spanish legal system recognizes instances of vicarious violence (*violencia vicaria*) in cases in which a person abuses or even kills their child in order to emotionally abuse their partner (or possibly only in cases in which a male partner abuses their child in order to harm their female partner). As noted in the article, there have been a number of convictions for vicarious abuse.

Of course, there are other reasons why some people might hurt their children, such as part of a pattern of abuse toward the children unrelated to spousal abuse, for the purpose of collecting life insurance money, as part of sexual abuse, and so forth, so presumably there exist certain criteria in the Spanish legal system to distinguish these cases.

What are the legal standards in Spain for classifying abuse or violent crimes against children as vicarious violence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article seems to state the legal standard which I repeat here in a Google Translate version:

> The former Government delegate for Gender Violence, Miguel Lorente ,
> defines vicarious violence as "violence that, when it seeks to hurt
> and harm women, instead of doing it directly, seeks to harm people who
> have special meaning for them."

Harming a child or other person with special meaning to the true target of the violence is, of course, already a serious crime in Spanish law.

A finding that the crime was a form of vicarious violence is a sentencing enhancing finding of fact by the court that makes a convicted defendant eligible for what U.S. lawyers would call "life in prison with possibility for parole" even though Google Translate provides a more literal translation from the Spanish of the words used to describe the enhanced sentence for which someone becomes eligible if this is established.

> Of course, there are other reasons why some people might hurt their
> children, such as part of a pattern of abuse toward the children
> unrelated to spousal abuse, for the purpose of collecting life
> insurance money, as part of sexual abuse, and so forth, so presumably
> there exist certain criteria in the Spanish legal system to
> distinguish these cases.

Other than the legal definition set forth above, there does not appear to be any further legal guidance for the courts in determining if this sentence enhancing fact has been established. It is merely a question of fact for the judges on the court to determine based upon the evidence presented at trial by the prosecution and reasonable inferences from that evidence.

Lawyers for the defendant can argue that this sentence enhancer should not apply because one of the different motives in the quoted material from the question was the actual or predominant motive, and the prosecution can argue that it was indeed vicarious violence, and then the judges have to decide whether they think that the prosecution has met its burden of proof to establish this motive and impose the enhanced sentence (which is authorized, but not required, even if it is established).

This isn't going to be the easiest point to make in a typical case for the defendant.

Usually, the defense is primarily going to be trying to cast doubt upon whether the prosecution has met its burden of showing that the defendant is guilty of the underlying crime at all, and, for example, having the defendant testify that he did it because he was a pedophile, rather than to hurt his wife is not going to help him all that much.

Instead, I would expect that the usual approach of the defendant's lawyer would be to argue that the prosecution's evidence, if believed, supports a prosecution theory of the case that, for example, this murder was about insurance money and not about intimidating the defendant's wife.

Another way the the defense could fight this sentencing enhancing claim at trial would be to argue that the specific evidence of the prosecution offer to show the defendant's alleged vicarious violence motive isn't credible in all of the ways the one generally casts doubt on the credibility of evidence in a court case. For example, the defense might offer evidence from a different witness than one offered by the prosecution that cast's doubt on the credibility of the prosecution's witness. Or, the defense might ask (or have the judges in the case ask) questions of the witness who is the key witness on the vicarious violence motive issue, that casts doubt on that witnesses' own testimony (perhaps by pointing out contradictions in the testimony or that the witnesses couldn't have been where the witness claimed to be in earlier testimony).

Also, it doesn't appear that vicarious violence has to be an either/or question. Nothing in the definition of vicarious violence suggests, for example, that a defendant can't both have a motive to collect insurance money, and a motive to intimidate the child's mother, at the same time, "killing two birds with one stone" so to speak.

Comment: I looked over the laws, and that does appear to be all there is. In fact, as far as I could tell, the original law against "violencia de género" does include "violencia vicaria" with more or less precisely that definition, but not by *name*, and the PSOE and Podemos are pushing to change the law to use the term. However, it looks like certain "autonomías" already use the term "violencia vicaria" explicitly. In any case, it might also be interesting to know how lawyers in particular cases have argued for or against considering a crime to be violencia vicaria.

Comment: It's also interesting to note the differing legal frameworks in the US or Spain. Upon checking the text of the current laws, it does look like it applies only to women, and the language is suggestive of violence by men in particular, though ultimately this last part is gender-neutral enough that I think a court would surely uphold it for intimate partner violence in lesbian relationships, and I have read an article or two by some LBGTQ-rights organizations that seem to support expanding its scope of application.

Comment: Compare that to the US Violence Against Women Act, which of course, despite the name and goal, applies to people and couples of all genders. I am not much of a Whorfian, but sometimes I wonder whether the two languages' gender systems have anything to do with it, if only a little: a law written in standard Spanish that covered people of any gender would use a lot of supposedly "generic" masculine pronouns, so it would look a whole lot like a law that only covered men to someone inclined to read it with a more feminist linguistic lens, which presumably wouldn't be popular among its advocates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand what the Spanish Penal Code is for "vicarious violence" look no further than the case of José Bretón. He was one of the first cases that became a turning point in our understanding of how complex domestic violence can become and turn into something we previously had no name for.

Comment: A link to the case which might be unfamiliar to a reader, together with a brief description of what it involved, would greatly improve this answer.